# MySQL works slow on Ubuntu when using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, jdbc

I have a production server with the following conf:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- jdk 8u111
- mybatis-3.4.1.jar
- MySQL 5.7.18
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar
- Connection string: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDB?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false

The problem is that every query that goes throw JDBC has some strange delay about 0.2 sec (no matter which query). It can be observed from java side and from remote tools like DbVis. At the same time mysql console executes queries without such delay. My development server on Windows (with MySQL) works fine. I've been googling the root of the problem several weeks without success...

I've tried the following steps:

1. Upgraded MySQL from 5.5 ->  5.7.18
2. Installed last JDBC driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar
3. Configured UTF-8 character_sets

   ```
   [mysql]
   default-character-set=utf8
   [mysqld]
   collation-server = utf8_general_ci
   character-set-server = utf8
   ```
4. Disabled DNS host names lookups

   ```
   [mysqld]
   skip-name-resolve
   ```

All of them don't help

Update:

I profiled one query by

```
SET SESSION profiling = 1;
SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 0, 50;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

and saw that the query took 0.00121975 sec. Sounds reasonable, but DbVis said that execution time is 0.156 sec. Time measurements in java show that queries took about 0.2 sec as well. So I believe that there are some time leaks in data transferring or connection stage

Comment: Outside mysql does java run without a problem (faster)?

Comment: Yes, java runs ok. As I mentioned even from DbVis all queries are executed with the same persistent delay (tunneling is used), so I don't suspect java.

Comment: Ok. I have experienced some sluggishness in ubuntu while using eclipse. I switched to openSuse and they went away

Comment: *"tunneling is used"* - So perhaps what you are seeing is a delay related to the tunneling. Do you use the same tunneling setup when you connect to your development database?

Comment: No, development env is on my notebook without any tunneling... The main problem is that on the production server there are java and MySql. Java executes SQL queries via JDBC and I observe persistent delays. I just noticed that DbVis with tunnneling has the same delay, so I believe there is one common problem here.